Sheafification of function presheaves
Let $X$ be a topological space, $Y$ a set, and let $\mathcal F$ be a presheaf on $X$ so that $\mathcal{F}(U)\subseteq Y^U$, for any open set $U$, and the restriction morphisms are function restriction. Now, define
$$  \mathcal{F}'(U) = \{f : U \to Y \mid \forall x \in U, \exists V^{\text{open}}, x \in V \subseteq U \text{ so that } f |_V \in \mathcal{F}(V)\}  \text{.}$$
I think $\mathcal{F}'$ is a sheaf with function restriction as the morphisms, and that it is isomorphic to the sheafification of $\mathcal F$. However, I am having trouble proving that $\mathcal{F}'$ even forms a presheaf, and I cannot find the isomorphism. How can I do this?
For background, I am a novice, self-studying Algebraic Geometry from Hartshorne's, currently attempting to understand schemes better. Thank you in advance.

I would start from the sheafification side. The idea is that you want to localize the information in your presheaf $\mathcal{F}$. Formally that means that the sheafification $\mathcal{F}^+$ is the collection of stalks that can locally be "grouped together" into elements of the form $f \in \mathcal{F}(V)$:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}^+(U) = \left\lbrace (s_p)_{p \in U} \mid \forall x \in U : \exists V^{\text{open}}: \exists f \in \mathcal{F}(V) : x \in V, f_p = s_p \text{ for all } p \in U  \right\rbrace.
\end{equation}
Here $f_p$ denotes the stalk of $f$ at $p$. Now this is just the formal side, but you want to relate it to your supposed sheaf $\mathcal{F}'$. Note that for given $x \in U$ the function $f \in \mathcal{F}(V)$ is not unique, but whenever you have two such functions $f \in \mathcal{F}(V), f' \in \mathcal{F}(V')$ their stalks agree on the overlap $V \cap V'$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
f_p = f'_p
\end{equation}
for all $p \in V \cap V'$. Since $f$ and $f'$ are actual functions, this means that $f$ and $f'$ agree as functions on a small neighborhood around each $p$, and therefore on all of $V \cap V'$. This condition lets us extend $f, f'$ as functions to $V \cup V'$ and in this fashion we get that an element of $\mathcal{F}^+(U)$ is indeed an actual function $f^+: U \to Y$.
As a last note: My argument that lets you identify sections of $\mathcal{F}^+(U)$ with functions is essentially the same thing that you would do to prove that $\mathcal{F}^+$ is a sheaf (at least the gluing property).
Best,
Clemens

I'm not sure I understand. Could you state the definition of the function associated with a given element of the sheafification more explicitly? I've previously made a few of the connections you made in your answer, but I was working with the explicit function $f^+(x)=s_x(x)$.

Nevermind, I've just realized what you mean. For future readers, the trick is to glue the $f$'s, which are compatible, as Clemens proves.
